# Continuous Map: Open $\iff$ Closed?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Is it true that a continuous map is open iff it is closed:
$$f\text{ continuous}:\quad f\text{ open}\iff f\text{ closed}$$

The idea is that when somebody asks for embeddings, quotient maps and homeomorphisms it is useful to know wether a continuous map is open/closed. But then the question arises wether in this context they become equivalent in the sense that an embedding that happens to be open automatically is closed and vice versa and similar for quotient maps and homeomorphisms respectively.

Comment: Ups got me, actually nothing ^^ I just got it into mind and thought it might be worthwhile for the stackexchange comjunity...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the inclusion $]0,1[ \to \mathbb{R}$ and the inclusion $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ah too bad I hoped that when thinking about embeddings quotients and homeomorphism being closed resp open might be equivalent but you're right obviously this is not the case as there are open embeddings that aren't closed and closed embeddings that aren't open as your example shows of course - totally forgot about that. But good that makes the question even more interesting - let me modify it.

Comment: By the way thanks for the really nice examples! Can u provide also examples for quotient maps respectively?

Comment: "But then the question arises wether in this context they become equivalent?" Almost never. But the question isn't really precise anyway.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\{b_0,b_1\}$ and define a topology on B whose open sets are $\emptyset, \{b_0\}, B$. Then the map $f:A\to B$ defined by $f(a)=b_0$ is open but not closed. Similarly you may define a map which is closed but not open.

Comment: If $f$ were a bijection, then only $f$ is open iff $f$ is closed.